# Does all evaluation happen from left to right?

Tags: java

```
String foo = null;

if(foo == null || foo.equals("")){
    //this is only safe if I'm guaranteed that the evaluation happens from left to right
}
```

In Java, is there such a guarantee? Or do I need to perform these tests in tandem to be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, java will short circuit a conditional with the OR operator from left to right.

> At run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; if
>   the result has type Boolean, it is subjected to unboxing conversion
>   (§5.1.8).
>
> If the resulting value is true, the value of the conditional-or
>   expression is true and the right-hand operand expression is not
>   evaluated.
>
> If the value of the left-hand operand is false, then the right-hand
>   expression is evaluated; if the result has type Boolean, it is
>   subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8). The resulting value becomes
>   the value of the conditional-or expression.

Comment: thanks, but is the order from left to right or right to left or does it depend on the VM?

Comment: a) It is decided at compile time, the JVM has nothing to do with it (it just processes the bytecode) and b) it is a standard

Comment: updated my answer with the quote from the spec showing left-to-right evaluation of OR operator in a conditional.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. From [JLS section 15.24](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24):

> The conditional-or operator `||` operator is like `|` (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false.

The fact that the right-hand operand won't even be evaluated unless the left-hand operand is true means it *has* to be evaluated left-to-right... but in fact, that's the case for *all* operators. From [JLS 15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

It's also true for method (and constructor) arguments. For example, from section 15.12.4.2 (Evaluate Arguments, part of Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation):

> The argument expressions, if any, are evaluated in order, from left to right. If the evaluation of any argument expression completes abruptly, then no part of any argument expression to its right appears to have been evaluated, and the method invocation completes abruptly for the same reason.

(It's interesting to note the "appears to" here - it's okay for the JVM to actually evaluate them out-of-order, so long as that's not observable...)

Answer (score 4):

The order is from left to right for `||`, '&&'.

For `||` operator. If it sees if `a||b`, if `a` is `false`, it will check for `b`.

Answer (score 3):

The `||` operator will [*short circuit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) if the left side is `true`. The left side is *always* evaluated first.

Yes, you are guaranteed that this code is safe: It will never throw a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) if `foo` is `null`.

---

FYI, your code fragment is typical for java code and is best practice.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **IT DEPENDS**.

In your case - YES, but generally speaking it depends on the operator.

For example **= (assign operator)** evalutation is performed from **right to left**

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

a = b = c;

System.out.println("a = " + a);
System.out.println("b = " + b);
System.out.println("c = " + c);
```

The result:

```
a = 3
b = 3
c = 3
```

Here you can find full list of Java operators and the order of evaluation: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Comment: thanks, I realize I could have worded the title better. I'm exclusively concerned about logical evaluation of conditions here.

Comment: I added a link to the full list of Java operators and their order or precedence.

Comment: Section 15.7 of the JLS clearly states that ALL binary operators are evaluated left to right - see the link in Jon's answer.  That includes the assignment operator.  However, the assignment operator ASSOCIATES from right to left, which doesn't imply that it's evaluated that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is misleading. The answer to your actual question is 'yes', as per the JLS, but 'all evaluation happens from left to right' definitely isn't true.

This is a common misunderstanding. Consider the expression `a+b*c`. What the JLS actually says about evaluation order is that operands *of an operator* are evaluated left to right. So `a,b,c` are evaluated in that order, whatever they are, e.g. functions. The *operators* are applied according to the specified operator precedence (which isn't actually very well specified in the JLS). So of course the multiplication happens before the addition.